# Spring boot ignores arguments passed after jvmArguments

Tags: spring-boot, maven, yaml

I'm trying to run one of my microservices in debug mode.
For these I added jvmArguments to a command that starts application.

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000" -Dspring.profiles.active="dev" -DAUTH0_CLIENT_ID="somevalue123" -DAUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET="somevalue123" -DACMS_CRYPTO_KEY="somevalue123" -DACMS_NODE_NAME="n/a" -DACMS_POD_IP="n/a" -DACMS_POD_NAMESPACE="n/a" -DACMS_POD_NAME="n/a"
```

As I'm using **.yml** file to provide client_id, client_secret and crypto_key I need to pass them also. Here is the config file:

```
acms:
  crypto:
    key: ${ACMS_CRYPTO_KEY}
  node:
    name: ${ACMS_NODE_NAME}
  pod:
    name: ${ACMS_POD_NAME}
    namespace: ${ACMS_POD_NAMESPACE}
    ip: ${ACMS_POD_IP}
  env:
    info:
      enabled: false
auth0:
  clientId: ${AUTH0_CLIENT_ID}
  clientSecret: ${AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET}
```

Without debug mode everything works fine. But when I'm adding

```
-Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000"
```

I receive and error: Application run failed

*org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'acmsConfig': Injection of autowired
dependencies failed; nested exception is
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **Could not resolve placeholder
'ACMS_CRYPTO_KEY' in value "${ACMS_CRYPTO_KEY}"***

So how can I add debug mode command without breaking other arguments?

Comment: Try to include all your java arguments with in the jvmArguments section instead of mentioning them individually with -D

Comment: Why not running from inside your IDE?

Comment: @SivaKumar you were right, I added all arguments inside and it worked! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

SivaKumar answer solved the problem. Working command looks like this:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000 -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -DAUTH0_CLIENT_ID=testid -DAUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET=testsecret -DACMS_CRYPTO_KEY=testkey -DACMS_NODE_NAME=n/a -DACMS_POD_IP=n/a -DACMS_POD_NAMESPACE=n/a -DACMS_POD_NAME=n/a"
```